# YouTrack: Pevent all emails when creating a Gantt Chart

Tags: youtrack

When I create a YouTrack Gantt Chart (using Build 2023.1.10518), as I add issues, modify the start dates and change estimations all the users who are already tagged/starred on the issue get "many" emails as I modify each of the issues.

Is there a way to prevent all the status update emails until editing the Gantt Chart has been completed?